# VBA executing Oracle 19c stored procedure with parameters using ADO is throwing error

Tags: vba, adodb, oracle19c

I'm trying to execute an Oracle stored procedure from a VBA macro and I'm getting this error:

> Watch :   : giCurPlanId : 24306945 : Long : DataAccessFns.exec_oracle_procedure
> Watch :   : adocmd.Execute : <ORA-06550: line 1, column 42:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'PO_RETURN_CURSOR' must be declared

This is the code

```
        dim ReturnCursor As ADODB.Recordset
        Set adocmd = New ADODB.Command
        strSQL = "{call " & "GET_TEST_DATA" & "( ?, ?, ?, {resultset 0, po_return_cursor})}"  
        
        adocmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        adocmd.CommandText = strSQL
        adocmd.Parameters.Append _
            adocmd.CreateParameter("pi_PlanId", adInteger, adParamInput)
            adocmd.Parameters(0).Value = giCurPlanId
        adocmd.Parameters.Append _
            adocmd.CreateParameter("pi_PyPlanId", adInteger, adParamInput)
            adocmd.Parameters(1).Value = -1                
        adocmd.Parameters.Append _
            adocmd.CreateParameter("po_return_code", adInteger, adParamOutput, 6)
            adocmd.Parameters(2).Value = 99

     'Execute the proc.  Proc must return cursor or will error?
     adocmd.Prepared = True
     Set ReturnCursor = adocmd.Execute
```

This is the code of the Oracle stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE GET_TEST_DATA(
            pi_PlanId         IN NUMBER  DEFAULT NULL,
            pi_PyPlanId       IN NUMBER  DEFAULT NULL,
            po_return_code    OUT INTEGER,
            po_return_cursor  IN OUT t_return_cursor)
AS
           v_PlanId          NUMBER(10,0);
           v_PyPlanId        NUMBER(10,0);
           e_sqlerror        EXCEPTION;
           v_return_code     INTEGER;

           v_nContinue       NUMBER(10,0);
           v_sSsaPlanId      VARCHAR2(3);
           v_nSizeofId       NUMBER(10,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append `po_return_cursor` parameter because it's declared as `IN OUT`.

Comment: do you how to append it? I know using oracle.dataaccess client but dont know using adodb client.